# mvc populate dropdownlist from ienumerable model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, ienumerable, dropdownlistfor

I have to populate **distinct** company name in Dropdownlistfor from

```
@model IEnumerable<Zykod.Data.Models.CUtilityModel>
```

I tried the following ways.  Nothing is working.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.Select(i => i.CompanyName).Distinct().ToList(), new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "input-large form-control" })

@Html.DropDownList("CompanyName", new SelectList(Model).Distinct())

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyName, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "input-large form-control" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Third attempt was the closest one.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyName",
                   new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.CompanyName).Distinct().ToList()),
                   new { @class = "input-large form-control" })
```

To explain a bit overload of `DropDownList` used here, its first param specifies the field that will hold the posted value, second param is for the list of possible values, and the third one, as you already figure out, is for various html attributes like class.

Note that in order to accept posted value in the controller, you need to make sure corresponding action method either accepts a `string CompanyName` parameter, or some object that has a property of the same name.

Comment: This wont work since the model is `@model IEnumerable<Zykod.Data.Models.CUtilityModel>` and `IEnumerable<T>` does not contain a property named `CompanyName`. The model should be an object containing a property to bind to and the collection (and the collection should ideally be configured in the controller to contain only distinct values).

Comment: @StephenMuecke, not sure I am following. Model is `IEnumerable<>`, so it has an extension method `Select`. Inside `Select` we have individual object of type `CUtilityModel`, which most likely contains `CompanyName` field, so we selecting that. While I agree this does not look as the cleanest view code, it should definitely work.

Comment: But your binding to property `model.CompanyName` but the model is `IEnumerable<T>` which does not contain a property named `CompanyName` (it would throw an exception). Your code would only work if you used `@Html.DropDownList("CompanyName", new new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.CompanyName) .... }` but this would mean in using `FormCollection` or adding a method parameter `string CompanyName` to access the posted value (not a good solution)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, oh, i see, thanks for pointing this out. I paid all attention to the list value. Fixed. As for accepting the posted value, string param can be acceptable, or OP could define a separate model class specifically to handle post request from this form.

Comment: @Andrei, I did add ..Html.DropDownList("dCompanyName", new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.CompanyName).Distinct()), "All",new { ..class = "input-large form-control" }).  How you will bind to controller to return model?

Comment: @KartheySundarem, assuming dCompanyName is just a typo (should be without d), you should have an action that will handle your post request, and it should have a parameter `string CompanyName`. Or you can define some model class that has a property CompanyName, and make that as an input parameter. There is also a common approach to define one model class for output (GET) and input (POST). In your case you would have a single class with properties for selected company name and for list of company names